# Having trouble using KeyEvent

Tags: java, keyevent, gridworld

My question is, how can I get my `move()` methods to work using `KeyEvents` i.e. `KeyEvent.VK_DOWN`?
I'm currently trying to use the `import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;` in which I'll be using the arrow keys NOT numpad keys to move a player in a 2 dimensional grid. I have my actions `moveUp();` `moveRight();` `moveDown();` and `moveLeft();` in my super class `User` and the class `Player extends User` and contains the key event method. When I use the arrow keys the actor simply does not move, however when I manually click on the actor in the grid and select a method it will move. Therefore my move methods work, so I'm assuming my KeyEvent setup is broken. Pictures showing me manually controlling the methods are supplied.

User which contains the move methods

```
package info.gridworld.actor;
import info.gridworld.grid.Grid;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

public class User extends Actor {
    private boolean isStopped = false;

    public User()
    {
        setColor(null);
    }

    public void moveUp(){
        moveTo(getLocation().getAdjacentLocation(Location.NORTH));
    }

    public void moveDown(){
        moveTo(getLocation().getAdjacentLocation(Location.SOUTH));
    }

    public void moveLeft(){
        moveTo(getLocation().getAdjacentLocation(Location.WEST));
    }

    public void moveRight(){
        moveTo(getLocation().getAdjacentLocation(Location.EAST));
    }
}
```

Player class contains KeyEvents

```
package game.classes;
import info.gridworld.actor.User;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Player extends User{

    public Player(){
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keys = e.getKeyCode();
        if((keys == KeyEvent.VK_UP)){
            moveUp();
        }
        else if((keys == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)){
            moveDown();
        }
        else if((keys == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)){
            moveLeft();
        }
        else if((keys == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)){
            moveRight();
        }
    }


}
```

Main class

```
package game.classes;
import info.gridworld.grid.*;

public class PlayerRunner{


    private static GameGrid world = new GameGrid();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        world.add(new Location(0, 0), player);
        world.show();
  }
}
```

[image: PreMove]

[image: moveDown() Selected]

Comment: I don't think that's how it works, doesn't `World` receive key information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a Bug in GridWorld with arrow keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671466/how-to-move-a-bug-in-gridworld-with-arrow-keys)

Comment: I would recommend to  use keyBinding for this

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will try that example I also did not see the keyPressed method in the ActorWorld class

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I thought that too, but the OP is using the `gridworld` API, which works slightly differently...not saying it's not possible, but if we can find something that works with the API it will produce better results, if that fails...hack, hack, hack ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer the problem with creating a new class that extends ActorWorld is that I won't have access to my move() methods.... If I delete the stock method keyPressed in World class will my methods work?

Comment: You should be able to access the `Actor` via `World#getGrid#get`...I think...not used the API before ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry I edited my comment right after you answered but if I deleted the KeyPressed method could I keep my original design?

Comment: No idea, what's the original design?

Comment: What I have in my question the User/Player setup I'm not really understanding the CharacterWorld setup you mentioned in the duplicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The World class actually has a keyPressed() method. You can just extend World and override this method. It will give you a string parameter to work with instead of a KeyEvent. Use javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(description).getKeyCode() to figure out which key was pressed. The source for the World class is her:  https://github.com/parkr/GridWorld/blob https://github.com/parkr/GridWorld/blob/master/framework/info/gridworld/world/World.java aster/framework/info/gridworld/world/World.java

As for getting access to your Actor's methods, I would put a reference to an Actor in the World class. Then when you add the Actor you want to move to the world, you can just set it there. Then when you're dealing with the keystrokes you have access to the Actor you want to manipulate.

Comment: Okay that should work but what's the reason for the location parameter? Is that the location of the actor? (getLocation();)?

Comment: Also I believe one of your links is broken, I couldn't edit my previous comment which is why I created this new one.

Comment: I think it's the Actor that's selected within the World gui. You shouldn't need it for what you're doing though

Answer (score 1):

You're extending Actor, which has nothing to do with the GUI, and KeyEvents and related are a swing thing.  You need to actually add a KeyListener to a JPanel.  From what I can tell, right now you just have the extra methods in the Actor class.

The GUI isn't actually on the AP test, so there's not a lot out there on it, but it looks like you can extend info.gridworld.gui.GridPanel.  So override the constructor as:

```
public GridPanel(DisplayMap map, ResourceBundle res)
{
    super(map, res);
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {
        // Put the KeyListener methods here. 
        // (All of them: KeyListener is an interface
    }
}
```

This is kind of rough, but I think it should work.

I assume you're going to have a reference to the Actor that you can move with the arrow keys anyway, so you can just call its move methods.

Comment: @user3709396 super(map, res); doesn't meet arguments in JPanel method and requires me to remove map and res.........` The constructor JPanel(DisplayMap, ResourceBundle) is undefined Remove arguments to match 'JPanel()'`

Comment: Also where would I put my move() methods? they're not accessible from the gridPanel and moving them to the grid panel doesn't work because I don't have access to location getters

Comment: Are you extending GridPanel or JPanel?

Comment: The whole thing is I don't understand what you're doing, are you modifying the constructor in GridPanel or are you saying create a separate class that does all of this? Put this in the player class the user class? I can create all of the KeyEvents and whatnot I just am confused on where to add this for it to work correctly?

Comment: Sorry but just realized this is a BAD way of going about this. Posted a better answer...